# How to create QueueTrigger in intellij?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am not able to see QueueTrigger option in a drop-down list when I want to add QueueTrigger function of azure functions in java, in the same project? How to enable it. We can select different trigger functions options while creating the project but if we want to add the new function then I am not able to see the QueueTrigger as well as BlobTrigger option. I have attached the image also. Thanks in advance. (I know we can create by copying code in another java class but want to know is there any other option available?).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqkp5.png)

Comment: If it's in the same project are all the classpaths/sources and maven configured correctly for the InteliJ to see/detect it correctly?

Comment: Yes it is already configured.